# How I can use Selenium methods while "finding" via Capybara methods?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, selenium-webdriver

As a result I have the instance of Capybara::Element and methods from Selenium::WebDriver::Element cant be used according to the present element. What I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#native` the get the element directly from the driver and execute its methods on it like so:

```
 your_element.native.desired_method(args)
```